# Create K8S Ingress TLS secret error: Secret in version "v1" cannot be handled as a Secret: illegal base64 data at input byte 1548

Tags: kubernetes, ssl, kubernetes-ingress

I try to create a Ingress TLS certificate secret in a yaml file. For getting the correct yaml content, I decide to create the secret through command line first:

```
kubectl create secret tls tls-secret --namespace demo --key=cert/private.pem --cert=cert/certificate.crt -o yaml
```

For example I get:

```
apiVersion: v1
  tls.crt: CERT_TEXT  
  tls.key: KEY_TEXT
metadata:
  name: tls-secret
  resourceVersion: "3802272"
  uid: a5d10767-cb8e-41f7-b0f8-68c194ae2584
```

Then I put the `tls.crt` and `tls.key` into the yaml file:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: tls-secret
  namespace: demo
type: kubernetes.io/tls
data:
  tls.crt: CERT_TEXT  
  tls.key: KEY_TEXT
```

And when I try to apply the yaml file `kubectl apply -f`, I got an error:

```
Error from server (BadRequest): error when creating ".\\tls-secret.yaml": Secret in version "v1" cannot be handled as a Secret: illegal base64 data at input byte 1548
```

I don't why I got this error, the certificate and key content is extractly as show in the terminal.

I tried encode the cert and key content with base64 encoding and replace original text with base64 one, but it now working, got error: `Warning: tls: failed to find any PEM data in certificate input`

Comment: What do you mean by "then I put the tls.crt and tls.key into the yaml file"? The `kubectl create secret` command is already producing a YAML file for you; you can just use it verbatim.

Answer (score 0):

If your key and cert files are correct, use this command:

```
 kubectl create secret tls tls-secret --namespace demo --key=cert/private.pem --cert=cert/certificate.crt
```

Or:

```
 kubectl create secret tls tls-secret --namespace demo --key=cert/private.pem --cert=cert/certificate.crt --dry-run=client -o=yaml > tls.yaml
 kubectl apply -f tls.yaml
```

If you get any errors, inspect content of key and cert files. You can use openssl for that.